# error of the table of Laguerre polynomials

Tags: tables

there are 4 rows overall in each of which an equation environment has been written. However, there is a problem with my codes. Help me out if possible.

```
    \begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Laguerre polynomials}
    \begin{tabular}{l}
    \hline \\[0.5ex]
    \begin{equation}
    n=0
    \begin{cases}
    L_{0}^{1}(z)= \\
    L_{0}^{2}(z)= \\
    L_{0}^{3}(z)= \\
    L_{0}^{4}(z)= \\
    L_{0}^{5}(z)= \\
    \vdots
    \end{cases}
    \end{equation}
    \hline \\[0.5ex]
    \begin{equation}
    n=1
    \begin{cases}
    L_{1}^{1}(z)= \\
    L_{1}^{2}(z)= \\
    L_{1}^{3}(z)= \\
    L_{1}^{4}(z)= \\
    L_{1}^{5}(z)= \\
    \vdots 
    \end{cases}
    \end{equation}
    \hline \\[0.5ex]
    \begin{equation}
    n=2
    \begin{cases}
    L_{2}^{1}(z)= \\
    L_{2}^{2}(z)= \\
    L_{2}^{3}(z)= \\
    L_{2}^{4}(z)= \\
    L_{2}^{5}(z)= \\
    \vdots 
    \end{cases}
    \end{equation}
    \hline \\[0.5ex]
    \begin{equation}
    n=3
    \begin{cases}
    L_{3}^{1}(z)= \\
    L_{3}^{2}(z)= \\
    L_{3}^{3}(z)= \\
    L_{3}^{4}(z)= \\
    L_{3}^{5}(z)= \\
    \vdots
    \end{cases}
    \end{equation}
    \hline \\[0.5ex]
    $\vdots$
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

Comment: You cannot use `equation` inside a tabular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code that works, but if you tell us what you want to achieve this can be improved.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Laguerre polynomials}
    \begin{tabular}{l}
    \hline 
    $\displaystyle
    n=0
    \begin{cases}
    L_{0}^{1}(z)= \\
    L_{0}^{2}(z)= \\
    L_{0}^{3}(z)= \\
    L_{0}^{4}(z)= \\
    L_{0}^{5}(z)= \\
    \vdots
    \end{cases}
    $\\[0.5ex]
    \hline 
    $\displaystyle
    n=1
    \begin{cases}
    L_{1}^{1}(z)= \\
    L_{1}^{2}(z)= \\
    L_{1}^{3}(z)= \\
    L_{1}^{4}(z)= \\
    L_{1}^{5}(z)= \\
    \vdots 
    \end{cases}
    $\\[0.5ex]
    \hline 
    $\displaystyle
    n=2
    \begin{cases}
    L_{2}^{1}(z)= \\
    L_{2}^{2}(z)= \\
    L_{2}^{3}(z)= \\
    L_{2}^{4}(z)= \\
    L_{2}^{5}(z)= \\
    \vdots 
    \end{cases}
    $\\[0.5ex]
    \hline 
    $\displaystyle
    n=3
    \begin{cases}
    L_{3}^{1}(z)= \\
    L_{3}^{2}(z)= \\
    L_{3}^{3}(z)= \\
    L_{3}^{4}(z)= \\
    L_{3}^{5}(z)= \\
    \vdots
    \end{cases}
    $\\[0.5ex]
    \hline 
    $\vdots$
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]